# Windows Phone Pivot Displaying above where it should

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Frame Height="Auto" Width="200" Background="Green" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Pivot Grid.Row="1" Background="Red" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Title="Pivot Title">
        <PivotItem Header="Blah">
            <TextBlock Text="Pivot content"/>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Which produces the following layout

[image: Screentshot]

The issue is that the pivot is appearing above where I would think it logically should appear. The pivot should appear below the half way mark but instead it is appearing about 27 pixels above it. I can of course just add a top margin to the pivot to push it back down but I'd like to get to the bottom of why it's appearing up there in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of that problem is that **vertical margin** of `Pivot` **depends on bounds mode of status bar**, as `Pivot` is intented to be the only child element of a page. If your bounds mode is set to `UseVisible` and your status bar is visible, then **pivot's vertical margin will be negative** (about -20, I think). So, if you add this code to the constructor:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow);
```

There'll be no vertical margin at all, and you will have expected behavior:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This does achieve what I want, but I am curious if it's possible to edit the template of the pivot control so that it has no margin regardless of the above mode.

Comment: @SynXsiS it's possible by removing `x:Name="RootElement"` for the container Grid. But I'm not sure if it won't break anything in pivot's behavior.