# Pivot control covering up stackpanel / image control

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a supposedly simple page, where I want to show a bar with an image at the top, and a pivot control just below it. For some reason, the pivot control just overlays half of the preceding stackpanel.
I tried adding a vertical margin, but I'm quite sure that's not the right way and I'd like to understand why it's not behaving as I was expecting.
This is the XAML code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="testPivot.list_test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SlideViewTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FFFF9300">
                <Image Margin="5,0,0,0"  Width="80" Height="50" Source="Assets/SmallLogo.png"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Pivot Background="#808080">
                <PivotItem Header="ONE">
                    <ListView Name="listOne" Foreground="Black">
                        <ListViewItem>ONE</ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>ONE</ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>ONE</ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>ONE</ListViewItem>
                    </ListView>
                </PivotItem>
                <PivotItem Header="TWO">
                    <ListView Name="listTwo" Foreground="Black">
                        <ListViewItem>TWO</ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>TWO</ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>TWO</ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>TWO</ListViewItem>
                    </ListView>
                </PivotItem>
                <PivotItem Header="FREE">
                    <ListView Name="listThree" Foreground="Black">
                        <ListViewItem>THREE</ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>THREE</ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>THREE</ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem>THREE</ListViewItem>
                    </ListView>
                </PivotItem>
            </Pivot>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

What I get:
[image: What I get]

What I expected:
[image: What I expected]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Pivot` margin is bounded to the status of the StatusBar.  Plus the Pivot is prose to be a top level control meaning nothing else on the page.

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow);
```

Will get your desire results.

See [Pivot Grid Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678324/windows-phone-pivot-displaying-above-where-it-should?rq=1) where the guy has the same problem but with Grid Row definitions.

Comment: Thank you, this works just fine, even though I find it odd there's no way to do this via XAML to get a correct preview Windows. My guess is this'll probably change in next framework versions.